# Multiple Network Interfaces with different local IPs talking to the same destination IP (different device)

Tags: networking, ip-address

I have a linux machine (Ubuntu) with multiple WiFi interfaces (let's call it the server). I need each interface (interface 1 and 2) to talk to a different instance of a device (same model device, device 1 and 2) which has the same destination address (10.1.1.1). Each interface on the server connects to a physically different instance of the device using DHCP. So the local IP addresses for the interfaces are like (e.g. 10.1.1.141 and 10.1.1.154).

How do I ensure that interface 1 communicates with device 1 and interface 2 communicates with device 2?

I cannot change the IP address of the devices (10.1.1.1) and the local IP address of the interfaces are provided by the devices using DHCP (10.1.1.141 and 10.1.1.154).

Thanks!